# What are the main differences between 京都弁(Kyoto-ben) and 大阪弁(Osaka-ben)

Tags: dialects, kansai-ben

These two dialects will sound very similar to an untrained ear. Can anyone highlight the main differences between these two dialects?

Answer (score 11):

According to [this Chiebukuro question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1315179928), there isn't that much of a difference in accents or words/phrases, and it's mainly the differences in the negative forms of `カ変` (kuru) and `サ変` (suru) verbs:

- Standard Japanese: 来ない・しない
- Osaka-ben: けえへん・せえへん
- Kyoto-ben: きいひん・しいひん

However, it should be noted that there is some overlap and some people in Kyoto use the Osaka forms and vice-versa.

Here are a few other notable differences mentioned:

- `いらっしゃい` is only said as `おこしやす` (and `おいでやす`) in Kyoto, not in Osaka. According to a [different Chiebukuro question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1412180814), `おいでやす` is said to first-time customers and `おこしやす` is said to regular customers.
- `え（～よ）` on the end of verbs and the `てね` in `よし（～してね）` is used much less frequently in Osaka than in Kyoto.
- `はる` is frequently added as an auxiliary verb to indicate a light degree of politeness. In Osaka-ben it apparently only indicates respect (`尊敬{そんけい}`) when used, but when used in Kyoto-ben it's also more broadly used as `丁寧語{ていねいご}`. Apparently one of the answerers feels uneasy when it's used with animals as in `犬が走ってはる`, but says it's perfectly normal to say this kind of thing in Kyoto.
- `～ねん` used on the end of verbs isn't used as much in Kyoto-ben as it is in Osaka-ben. `あの人何かしているよ` in standard Japanese can be `あの人なんかやってんで～？` in Osaka-ben and `あの人なんかしてはるよ？` in Kyoto-ben. However, the Kyoto-ben `してんで` and Osaka-ben `やっとるで` are often interchanged, and even in Osaka some people still use `してんで`.
- It's mentioned that many people in Osaka talk at a faster pace and have a slightly "rougher" tone than in Kyoto.
- Additionally, I think one other very commonly used word that wasn't mentioned might be `おぶ` used in place of `お茶` in Kyoto.

Links which might be useful:

- At http://www.arkys.net/kyotoben.html there's a list of comparison phrases (mainly comparing standard Japanese with Kyoto-ben, but I think it still might be useful.)
- http://www.akenotsuki.com/kyookotoba/ for an in-depth look at Kyoto-ben (and [many relevant words/phrases](http://www.akenotsuki.com/kyookotoba/goishuu/)) and at the [College of Liberal Arts at the University of Texas](http://www.laits.utexas.edu/japanese/joshu/kyookotoba/) for an incomplete translation of that same site. Particularly the [list of differences between Osaka-ben and Kyoto-ben](http://www.akenotsuki.com/kyookotoba/keihan.html).
- [Check this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20081020101540/http://www1.ocn.ne.jp/%7Etsujii/language.html) for a more comprehensive list of words used in Kyoto by Maiko and Geisha.
- [Here's a site](http://www.kansaiben.com/) in English that is designed for learning Kansai-ben and includes a pretty large set of video and audio examples. It mainly contrasts between kansai-ben and standard Japanese, but there is also a information about Osaka-ben (especially in the grammar notes).

(I'm mainly translating this because I wanted to know more myself so there are probably errors, but it's CW so feel free to edit/add to this!)

Answer (score 8):

Syockit already suggests in the answer, but to expand on this, consonant-ending verbs take different negative forms:

Negative forms (WRITE-NEGATION)

- Kyoto dialect: `書かへん` (kak-ahen)
- Osaka dialect: `書けへん` (kak-ehen)
- Hyogo dialect: `書きひん`  (kak-ihin)

Since the negative form of Osaka dialect is confusing with the potential form, Osaka dialect prefers the long form potential form.

Negative potential forms (WRITE-POTENTIAL-NEGATION)

- Kyoto dialect: `書けへん` (kak-e-hen)
- Osaka dialect: `書かれへん` (kak-are-hen)
- Hyogo dialect: `書けひん`  (kak-e-hin)

Answer (score 5):

What I see often is that Kyoto-ben has this emphasis expression "～え" sentence ending, like "ええお天気どすえ", "いきまっせ!" (ますえ contracted to まっせ), while Osaka-ben will use "～で" sentence ending, like "そないあほなことすると怪我するで。気をつけなあかんで。". Osaka is more likely to use わ ending.

Also, some verbs like 来ない are pronounced differently: Kyoto is きいへん while Osaka is けえへん (or was it the other way around? What about こおへん?)