# What does 消耗せえへんし mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, usage, kansai-ben

I just read a sketch written by 又吉 直樹さん, and here is a sentence:

> 動かんからエネルギーは消耗せえへんし腹減らんねん。

The part of 消耗せえへんし makes me feel a little confused. I probably know it means “doesn’t consume much so”, but I wanna know the specific grammatical instructions. Is this a Kansai-ben expression?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3588/9831

Comment: こういう質問で敬称の「さん」とか使われても、別に「丁寧な人やなあ」とか思わへんし・・

Comment: では、ここで「さん」を削除した方がいいのでしょうか？

Comment: @l'électeur さんはたぶん、「思わ**へん**し」を使ってみたかったんちゃうかな？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is Kansai-ben.

> 動か**ん**からエネルギーは消耗**せえへん**し腹減ら**んねん**。

means

> 動かないからエネルギーは消耗しないし腹が減らないのだ。

エネルギーは消耗せえへん means エネルギーは(← は replacing を)消耗しない, "I don't consume energy".